# How to access final balance from blockchain

Tags: php, blockchain

I have the following url:

```
https://blockchain.info/multiaddr?active=1AT4ES3ee1N6iBzzbdK8xvcAV3CBTRKcbS|1FHcYth4LRJMwNx2y8NR5DH7sYCiVzXs3Y&n=1
```

I want to access the final_balance from the output of the url.

I have the following code:

```
 $value = file_get_contents($url);
    $FinalBalance = $value["final_balance"];
    var_dump($FinalBalance);

Error PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'final_balance'
```

I also tried the following code:

```
 $value = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($value);
    var_dump($json);
        $FinalBalance = $json["final_balance"];
    var_dump($Final_Balance);
Error PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

Comment: since when does [`file_get_contents(): string|false`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) return an `array`? And `json_decode($value);` returns an object, again not an `array` - Set flag `json_decode(...,true)` for associative array.

Comment: In your second try you probably need `json_decode($value, true)` to access values (associative) array style like you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are near to finish that stuff but I will write down desired solution. Please have a look.

```
 $url="https://blockchain.info/multiaddr?active=1AT4ES3ee1N6iBzzbdK8xvcAV3CBTRKcbS|1FHcYth4LRJMwNx2y8NR5DH7sYCiVzXs3Y&n=1";
 $value = file_get_contents($url);
 $FinalBalance = $value;
 $data=json_decode($FinalBalance);
 echo $data->wallet->final_balance;
 echo $data->addresses[0]->final_balance;
 echo $data->addresses[1]->final_balance;
 exit;
```

You are going to access the inner object so you have to provide proper reference whether it is an array or an object.